# CCK E-mail field, display e-mail form in js dialog

Tags: 6, entities

I set display cck field to 'e-mail contact form'. It lead to page like email/15/field_email.

Is this possible to display that form in modal dialog? Which modules I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a few lines of JavaScript.

All you need to do is to create a iframe that links the the clicked link and then open it in a dialog. jQuery UI has support for dialogs. There is modules for [integrating jQuery UI](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui) and [upgrading your jQuery version](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) (if needed).

Once that is done, you can add the JavaScript to your theme to create the wanted effect.